# Which tax forms will I get for the return of an excess deferral?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, 401k

I worked at two jobs during 2016, and I contributed to my 401(k) through both companies. I realized recently that I had contributed more than the $18,000 limit. I notified the second (current) employer of my mistake and the plan administrator sent me a check, along with a letter describing how much of the amount was the original excess deferral, how much was the associated earnings, and how much of the latter had been withheld.

Aside from the letter I got, will I receive a revised W-2 or a 1099-R for 2016? What about for 2017?

Answer (score 1):

According to [investopedia](http://www.investopedia.com/ask/answers/158.asp) (not gospel, but fairly reliable), yes, you should:

> In addition, if the excess amount was deferred on a pre-tax basis, your employer must amend your W-2 to show the returned amount as wages.

Your employer may not be aware of this, however, so I would contact their payroll department to make sure that you get an updated W-2.

Comment: I explicitly asked my payroll department whether they were going to send me a new W-2 and they said they don’t need to. Is there any chance you can find an IRS source for your answer? (It seems logical to me that they would need to issue a new W-2, since several of the numbers on it are now different…)

Comment: I can;t find an IRA page that mentions it specifically, but ask them how you are supposed to account for the returned amount on your taxes.  If they don't know, ask them what they'll do when the IRA detects a discrepancy between what you file and what they report?   Do NOT file it as a "normal" distribution or you'll pay a 10% penalty.  You might also check with a local CPA for advice.